How do I display my output as a complex number with decimals for the real and imaginary components?
This is my code: 
c=Integrate[t/(E^t-1),{t,-Pi,Pi}]/(2Pi) a[j_]:=Integrate[t*Cos[j*t]/(E^t-1),{t,-Pi,Pi}] b[j_]:=Integrate[t*Sin[j*t]/(E^t-1),{t,-Pi,Pi}]
f[x_]=Sum[Cos[k*x]a[k]+ Sin[k*x]b[k],{k,0,2}]/Pi-c f[0]
However, this outputs a big jumbled mess of constants and weird functions, when all I want is a number like a+bi. I tried DecimalForm[f[0]], but that did nothing - it probably doesn't work for complex numbers. Thoughts?

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Do you want to have numerical values? Then simply use N, namely N[f[0]], and you will get back 1.01853 + 5.12751*10^-10 I.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

c = Integrate[t/(E^t - 1), {t, -Pi, Pi}]/(2 Pi);
a[j_] := Integrate[t*Cos[j*t]/(E^t - 1), {t, -Pi, Pi}];
b[j_] := Integrate[t*Sin[j*t]/(E^t - 1), {t, -Pi, Pi}];
f[x_] = Sum[Cos[k*x] a[k] + Sin[k*x] b[k], {k, 0, 2}]/Pi - c;

LeafCount /@ {f[x], f[x] // FullSimplify}

(* {498, 277} *)

f[x_] = f[x] // FullSimplify;

Complicated calculations should be done with arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision.
Table[f[0] // N[#, prec] &, {prec, {MachinePrecision, 15, 25}}]

(* {1.01853 + 5.06944*10^-10 I, 1.018530050745951 + 0.*10^-16 I, 
 1.0185300507459511388569666 + 0.*10^-26 I} *)

% // Rationalize[#, 0] & // N

{1.01853 + 5.06944*10^-10 I, 1.01853, 1.01853}

f[x] is real for real x
N[f /@ Range[-5, 5], 6] // Rationalize

(* {0.425581, 0.184143, 1.88773, 2.61998, 1.45042, 1.018530, 0.676771, \
0.0445855, 1.326078, 2.68711, 1.79941} *)

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]


FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]

(* 2 π *)

f[x] == f[x + 2 Pi] // Simplify

(* True *)

